# How to convert T-SQL into LINQ

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, t-sql

I have following code in a T-SQL query and I need to convert (rewrite) it into LINQ. Can somebody help me? Thanks

```
SELECT (select max(X.PocetDniPoPlatnosti) 
from
(

select 

(select top 1 datediff(day,datumplatnosti,getdate()) from planrealizace p 
where p.cinnostsopidsop = cinnostsop.idsop and datumplatnosti <= getdate() and p.provest = 1 and p.datumprovedeni is null
order by p.datumplatnosti desc) as PocetDniPoPlatnosti

from cinnostsop
where cinnostSOP.LegislativneVyznamna = 1 and (CinnostSOP.ObjektId = 131476)) X) as PoPlatnosti
```

Comment: Show us [what ***you*** have tried so far](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) - where are you stuck?

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.sqltolinq.com/downloads ?

Comment: I Tried linquer but that software does not support some function like datediff so it can't convert this code

Answer (score 0):

this should work, but I could not try it as I do not have any programming tools at home, so feel free to let me know if this doesn't work, and we can improve it together

```
var max = (from cp in cinnostsop.Where(c => c.LegislativneVyznamna = 1 && c.ObjektId = 131476) 
           join p in (
               planrealizace.
               Where(pz => pz.datumplatnosti <= DateTime.Now && 
                           pz.provest = 1 and pz.datumprovedeni is null).
               GroupBy(pz => pz.cinnostsopidsop, pz => pz).
               Select(g => 
                   new { 
                           id = g.Key, 
                           firstdate = (g.OrderByDescending(
                                              pz => pz.datumplatnosti).
                                          First().datumplatnosti - DateTime.Now
                                        ).Totaldays
                        })
               ) on cp.idsop equals p.id
           select p.firstdate).Max(d => d);
```

Comment: new { cinnostsopidsop I think here will be some problem, where can I get it?

Comment: Should be fine, new { cinnostsopidsop = g.Key } is creating an anonymous object which has a property called cinnostsopidsop and it's value is the group's key. As we group by pz.cinnostsopidsop, the key for the group will be cinnostsopidsop. If you not quite sure how this syntax work, just google 'anonymous object'

Comment: Maybe I should give it a new name so that it won't be confusing. Check the answer.